# AWS Codebuild is not updating artifacts in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm noticing that artifact file is not getting updated through AWS code build. In our case we are packaging artifacts into some xyz.zip under a folder in S3. We are using caching in CodeBuild and only when the cache file is manually deleted from s3, we are seeing new artifacts getting uploaded to S3.

This clearly appears to a bug in CodeBuild but would like to know if there is any automated way to get S3 artifacts uploaded at the end of each build?

Comment: Is the CodeBuild build being started by CodePipeline or some other way? I notice you have CodePipeline tagged.

Comment: Yes. It's code pipeline driven

Comment: Are you talking about the artifacts in the CodePipeline S3 artifact bucket? When run from CodePipeline CodeBuild will upload artifacts to the CodePipeline bucket rather than the CodeBuild one.